# Android Draw shadow around a bitmap ( On the edges only )

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-view

I m working on a custom view. I need to draw shadow at the edges of a bitmap. I have already drawn a border around it. But It is not what I required. With this code

```
protected Bitmap addBorderAtEdges(Bitmap srcBitmap, int borderWidth, int borderColor) {
        Bitmap dstBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                srcBitmap.getWidth() + borderWidth * 2, // Width
                srcBitmap.getHeight() + borderWidth * 2, // Height
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888 // Config
        );

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(dstBitmap);

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(borderColor);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(borderWidth);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        Rect rect = new Rect(
                borderWidth / 2,
                borderWidth / 2,
                canvas.getWidth() - borderWidth / 2,
                canvas.getHeight() - borderWidth / 2
        );


        canvas.drawRect(rect, paint);
        canvas.drawBitmap(srcBitmap, borderWidth, borderWidth, null);
        srcBitmap.recycle();

        return dstBitmap;
    }
```

This is what I achieved so far
[image]

This is what I trying to achieve [[image: 2]]

Sorry for my bad paint skills

This is not limited to this image only. The user can add any icon he wants and I have to draw the border on edges like this. One thing is sure that the icon will have a single color background and image contain only one icon ( Just like one I uploaded ). Any suggestions?

Comment: Y do I need to blur it?

Comment: I want to draw the border. But over the edges. Check the images again.